# Error returning data from json with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hi guys i have the next code

```
function getclientip() {
$.getJSON("http://192.168.127.2/getipclient.php?callback=?", function(json) {
eval(json.ip);
});}
```

this function is for get ip addrees of the visitors clients
on result i get

```
({"ip":"192.168.15.149"});
```

my problem is when i send data to other function

```
BtnClickGetIP: function(inSender, inEvent) {
this.USER_ADD_CONTENT.setDisplayValue(getclientip());
},
```

on fire bug i get the:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
192.168.15.149 dojo_build.js (line 145, col 7)
```

Comment: `getclientip()` doesn't return anything. It doesn't make much sense to call `setDisplayValue(getclientip());`. And why do you call `eval()` on json.ip?

Comment: this is line is of the wavemaker is a apps to make java applications

Comment: when i cal eval on json.ip i see the result on firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getClientIP(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://192.168.127.2/getipclient.php?callback=?", function(json) {
        callback(json.ip);
    });
}

BtnClickGetIP: function(inSender, inEvent) {

    var that = this;

    getClientIP(function(ip) {
        that.USER_ADD_CONTENT.setDisplayValue(ip);
    })
}
```

Comment: what about some information about what you did? not very useful answer otherwise.

Comment: i test this new function buy i get the error: TypeError: callback is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

eval(wm.load("resources/dlogin/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"));

Answer (score 0):

ajax is asynchronous call ，you can't just return the $.getJSON().use callback do your thing.
If you really want program like this. Use $.ajax function and set async=false